# rosdep equivalent of pip freeze and pip install requirements.txt

Tags: rosdep, docker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does rosdep have a way to save requirements to a flat file (possibly with frozen versions) and then install from that file later? I'm creating my ROS environment within Docker, and having such a file is nice because it's easy to repeatably build images, and creates a full dependency list that is easily inspected and version controlled. If not, there are other ways to build the image, but I figured I'd ask first.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236249/rosdep-equivalent-of-pip-freeze-and-pip-install-requirements.txt/) by [mrjogo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1576/mrjogo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 164 on 2016-06-06

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, rosdep does not have a mechanism for specifying versioned dependencies.

Further, the ROS repository does not maintain past versions of binary (deb) packages, so if you want to make repeatable builds you should keep your own base images with ROS installed, or snapshot the ROS repository and install from that snapshot.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2